# How would you align the left side of a div to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a stack of divs down the center of the page (using margin:auto)

now I want to draw a line starting at the center and extending to the right (say 400 pixels). I'm a but stumped, any idea how to make this work nicely?

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd just use margins:

Set to the left of the midline:

```
.leftSide {
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 50% 0 auto;
 background: #555;
 border: #777 1px solid;
}
```

or right side of midline

```
.rightSide {
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 50%;
 background: #555;
 border: #777 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this css:

```
div.line
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify position:relative on the surrounding container for this div. Otherwise position:absolute may not work as expected.

Comment: I see, it didn't work because I have 7 divs all stacked on top of each other. You'll need to set the top position for each div.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.line
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 400px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the content inside another tag.

And style the tag as following(for example a div):

```
div.special_tag {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```